# Rest with congruences

Tags: number-theory

Find the remainder of the division of $619^{1367}$ by $15$.

I cannot see what the initial congruence associated with the problem would be. Any tips?

Comment: BTW, in English, we usually call it the [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder), not the rest. In the context of modular arithmetic, it may be called the residue, especially in older books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $619^{1367}\equiv 4^{1367}\mod 15$.

Since $4^2=16$ and $16\equiv 1\mod 15$, we can use this here, by manipulationg the exponent.

$4^{1367}=4\cdot 4^{1366}=4\cdot 16^{683}$.

So $4^{1367}\equiv 4\cdot 16^{683}\equiv 4\cdot 1\equiv 4\mod 15$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Note $619 = _{15} 4$ and that $4^2 = _{15}1$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$15=3×5$$
$$\phi(15)=15(1-\frac 13)(1-\frac 15)=8$$

By Fermat, since $gcd(619,15)=1$

$$619^8\equiv 1 \mod 15$$

now, observe that $ 1376=172×8$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that $15$ divides $615$. So, $619 \equiv 615+4 \equiv 4 \pmod {15}$. This means that $619^{1367} \equiv 4^{1367} \pmod {15}$.

Next, note that $4^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {15}$. Therefore, $(4^2)^683 \equiv 4^{1366} \equiv 1 \pmod {15}$, and multiplying by $4$ gives $619^{1367} \equiv \boxed{4} \pmod {15}$.